# Working with multiple breadcrumbs in a knowledge base

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am working with Heroic Knowledge Base, and I am having trouble getting only one breadcrumb to show up (their suggested CSS code is not working). Unfortunately, I am not a PHP expert, and I am not sure how to edit the code so that it only shows one of the lines that it is pulling (we don't care which one) I have added the PHP from their breadcrumbs file. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 
/**
* Breadcrumbs template
*/ 
?>

<?php if(hkb_show_knowledgebase_breadcrumbs()): ?>
<!-- .hkb-breadcrumbs -->
<?php $breadcrumbs_paths = ht_kb_get_ancestors(); ?>
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs_paths as $index => $paths): ?>
        <ol class="hkb-breadcrumbs" itemscope 
itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
            <?php $last_item_index = count($paths)-1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($paths as $key => $component): ?>
                <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope 
itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
                    <?php if($key==$last_item_index): ?>
                        <span itemprop="item">
                            <span itemprop="name"><?php echo 
$component['label']; ?></span>
                    </span> 
                <?php else: ?>
                    <a itemprop="item" href="<?php echo $component['link']; ?>">
                        <span itemprop="name"><?php echo $component['label']; ?></span>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <meta itemprop="position" content="<?php echo $key+1; ?>" />
            </li>               
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue using the following code, however I would like to make it so that it is only effective when there is more than one.. the code below worked on articles with two breadcrumbs, but when there is only one it hid them all together.

```
ol.hkb-breadcrumbs {
    display: table-column-group;
}
```